# RESTful API authentication using Spring Boot and LDAP

Tags: api, spring-boot, ldap, restful-authentication

I have a requirement to build a RESTful API to authenticate users via LDAP(External LDAP) on Angular front end.  I have tried various option but it doesn't seem to work. I guess it could be related to the way LDAP credentials are set.

Here is the LDAP config in application.properties.

```
ldap.enabled=true
####### LDAP ##############
ldap.urls=ldap://test.ldap.com:389/ <br>
ldap.base.dn=dc=comp,dc=company,dc=com<br>
ldap.username=cn=q123123,ou=health,ou=internal<br>
ldap.password=johnwick123<br>
ldap.user.dn.pattern=uid={0}<br>
```

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final Logger LOG =
          LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);
  @Value("${ldap.urls}")
  private String ldapUrls;
  @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
  private String ldapBaseDn;
  @Value("${ldap.username}")
  private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;
  @Value("${ldap.password}")
  private String ldapPrincipalPassword;
  @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
  private String ldapUserDnPattern;
  @Value("${ldap.enabled}")
  private String ldapEnabled;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


    try {
          auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource().url(ldapUrls + ldapBaseDn).managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal)
              .managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword).and().userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOG.error("Handle exception here");
      throw ex;
    }
  }



    @Bean
      public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
                   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
}
```

Input to Spring Boot API is { "username":, "password": }

Output from Spring Boot API is { "status": 200, "message": "user authenticated"}

Comment: And your logs say what when the server in debug?